# Django-REST-Framework - create element with list of elements

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a 2 models. `A` and `B`. model `B` has a ForeignKey field to model `A` so in practice, `A` has a list of `B` elements.
I'm posting the following data to a Django-REST-Framework api.

```
{"a_field_1": "value1", "bs": [{"b_field_1": "value1", "b_field_2": "value2"}]}
```

These are my Serializers:

```
class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ('b_field_1', 'b_field_2')


class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    bs = BSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('a_field_1', 'bs')
```

When I post to my API i get this error:

```
The `.create()` method does not support writable nestedfields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `app.serializers.ASerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

I found `drf_compound_fields` package and wrapped the `bs` field in the ASerializer like so

```
bs = ListField(BSerializer(many=True))
```

This created the A object but didn't create the composite B elements.
When i changed the field name to `b_set` (instead of `bs`) i got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

What is the proper way to serialize and create a single element with a list of composite elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `create` method if you want to create the `B` objects as well.

From the documentation of [Writable Nested Serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers):

> By default nested serializers are `read-only`. If you want to support write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create `create()` and/or `update()` methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the `many=True` kwarg if you already use ListField.
But you should be looking at the solution provided by AKS.